# What's the difference between using a decorator and explicitly calling it?

Tags: python, decorator

Let's assume we have a decorator:

```
def decor(function):
    def result():
        printf('decorated')
        return function()
    return result
```

What is the difference between following code:

```
@decor
def my_foo():
    print('my_foo')
```

and:

```
def my_foo():
    print('my_foo')
my_foo = decor(my_foo)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your last code snippet is almost the definition of a decorator.  The only difference is that in the first case, the name `decor` is evaluated before the function definition, while in the second case it is evaluated after the function definition.  This only makes a difference if executing the function definition changes what the name refers to.

Nonsensical example:

```
def decor(function):
    def result():
        printf('decorated')
        return function()
    return result

def plonk():
    global decor
    decor = lambda x: x
    return None
```

Now

```
@decor
def my_foo(foo=plonk()):
    print('my_foo')
```

is different from

```
def my_foo(foo=plonk()):
    print('my_foo')
my_foo = decor(my_foo)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for explaining. The example is indeed is cool ;-)

Comment: I'm sorry.. but can someone please elaborate this answer?  It seems like there is an insight but I don't get it... Maybe 10k + reps can only  understand..?!

Comment: @ToussaintLouverture The original question asked about the difference between two code snippets of virtually identical semantics, so this answer tries hard to find a situation where these two code snippets are actually different.  Since in practice the code snippets are the same, this requires some nonsensical code: you need to write a function _definition_ which changes a global name as a side effect.  No one in their right mind would write such code, but it's a fun example.

Answer (score 4):

There isn't a difference. The `@decorator` syntax simply makes it easier to understand that a decorator is being applied. (This is an example of [syntactic sugar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar).)

Answer (score 1):

If there is a difference, is that python versions prior to Python 2.4 does not support the @decorator syntax while the explicit decorator call is supported since the stone age. Also, the @decorator syntax had to be applied at function definition and had to use the same function name, while the explicit decorator call can be applied later and can rename the decorated function.

Use the @decorator syntax unless you had a **really, really, really** good reason not to; which is almost never.